# creating a docusign envelope from template with api created user profile

Tags: docusignapi

given a demo docusign account with a template, through the api i have created a group with default permission profile of "Docusign Sender" and created a user profile and a membership to the group.  using the new user profiles creds (and the account id of the parent docusign account), i can fetch templates shared by the docusign account but i cannot create an envelope from such a template.  the error message received is:

```
USER_LACKS_PERMISSIONS : This user lacks sufficient permissions to access this resource
```

i can post more details if necessary but perhaps this is a well-known behavior that i just have been unable to resolve through researching the api and stackoverflow.

Comment: It sounds like you're accessing a template on another account or to a template that they do not have access to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems this particular error message is what happens when a user profile attempts to create an envelope (at least from a template in this case) while specifying a bccEmailAddresses recipient under emailSettings.  if this bcc recipient is removed, envelope creation succeeds.  of course, specifying a bcc recipient is no problem using the parent account's credentials.

Answer (score 0):

We discussed that you are using REST to grab shared templates to create envelopes.

When creating a user profile from API those users do not have the correct permission set. When creating the same user from the web console it works. One suggestion might be to grab the permission set of an known good user and compare it to the profile obtained from a user created by your API request:

https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Get%20Use%20Profile.htm?Highlight=profile

https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Get%20Group%20Information.htm